# Playback Stutters using NAudio

Tags: vb.net, naudio

When I playback an audio file (Wave), I here stuttering.

I tried changing the order of instantiation of the ISampleProviders I am chaining together.

Public Property FilePath() As String
        Get
            Return m_FilePath
        End Get

```
    Set(ByVal New_FilePath As String)
        Try
            Dim nCount As Integer = 0
            Dim retval As Integer = 0

            If New_FilePath.Length = 0 Then
                DisposeInputResources()
                m_FilePath = ""
                ChangeStatus_Controls(False)
                Exit Property
            End If

            PositionTrackBar.Value = 0
            m_Position = 0
            m_LastPosition = 0
            durationLabel.Text = ConvertTime(0)
            m_FilePath = New_FilePath
            DisposeInputResources()
            AudioFileReader1 = New AudioFileReader(FilePath)
            playerStatus = PhilipsStatus.stopped
            SpeedControl = New VarispeedSampleProvider(AudioFileReader1, 100, New SoundTouchProfile(False, False))
            SpeedControl.PlaybackRate = 1
            AutomaticGainControl = New SoftLimiter(SpeedControl)
            AutomaticGainControl.Boost.CurrentValue = fileAmplificationTrackBar.Value / 2
            'AudioFileReader1 = New AudioFileReader(FilePath)
            'Equalizer1 = New EqualizerClass(AudioFileReader1, bands)
            'SpeedControl = New VarispeedSampleProvider(Equalizer1, 100, New SoundTouchProfile(False, False))
            'SpeedControl.PlaybackRate = 1
            'VolumeSampleProvider1 = New VolumeSampleProvider(SpeedControl)
            audioLengthLabel.Text = ConvertTime(AudioFileReader1.TotalTime.TotalSeconds)
            AudioFileReader1.CurrentTime = TimeSpan.Zero
            If WaveOut1 IsNot Nothing Then WaveOut1.Stop()
            WaveOut1 = New WaveOutEvent()
            WaveOut1.Init(AutomaticGainControl)
            Thread.Sleep(1000)
            nCount = 60
            Volume = m_Volume
            Speed = m_Speed
            Position = 0
            PressStopKey()
            Dim sWAVFileName As String = Nothing

            If Path.GetExtension(New_FilePath).ToUpper() = ".DSS" Then
                sWAVFileName = Path.ChangeExtension(New_FilePath, "WAV")
                'I assume that ConvertDSSToWAV() has already been called to convert the .DSS to .WAV if necessary
                New_FilePath = sWAVFileName
                m_FilePath = sWAVFileName
            End If

            PositionTrackBar.Maximum = AudioFileReader1.TotalTime.TotalSeconds
            PositionTrackBar.Minimum = 0
            PositionTrackBar.LargeChange = PositionTrackBar.Maximum * 0.1
            If PositionTrackBar.LargeChange = 0 Then PositionTrackBar.LargeChange = 1
            PositionTrackBar.SmallChange = PositionTrackBar.Maximum * 0.01
            If PositionTrackBar.SmallChange = 0 Then PositionTrackBar.SmallChange = 1
            PositionTrackBar.TickFrequency = PositionTrackBar.SmallChange
            ChangeStatus_Controls(True)
        Catch ex As Exception
            MessageBox.Show("Property Set FilePath(New_FilePath= " & New_FilePath & ")" & vbCrLf & ex.Message, "FootPedalsControl", MessageBoxButtons.OK, MessageBoxIcon.Error)
        End Try
    End Set
End Property
```

in this code, I chain the ISampleProviders and pass them to WaveOut.Init each time i load a new file.  I stop the WaveOut first.

Expecting a smooth listen experience (dictation).
Actual Results: The playback stutters.

Comment: This C# looks a bit suspicious ;-)

Comment: It works except the playback stutters at times.  What do you mean by suspicious?

Comment: It's `VB` :-) ..... I was just kidding. In general this is a hard question to answer because the setup will be difficult to replicate.

Comment: Oh, lol!  I forgot this part of the code is VB.  The rest of my code is C#.  I did fix the problem thanks to Mark Heath.  I found an article he wrote years ago.  I had read the article a few months back but as these things go you do always get a full understanding of them on the first pass.  Thank you for trying!  And thanks to Mark Heath for his dedication to this field!

Comment: Is there a way I can mark this question as answered.  By the way, if anyone wants to know what I did, here's the answer.  I destroy the signal chain each time I stop the playback and recreate it on the next playback.

Comment: You can post your own answer, you might even get an upvote for it. But, try to keep the answer short and pinpoint the solution.

Answer (score 2):

This solved my problem:  Each time I stop the playback, I destroy the signal chain.  When playback is initiated again, I rebuild the signal chain.